# Tensorflow - Generating a Tensorboard embedding with batching?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

Pretty straight forward question:

There's a great example from the 2017 Tensorflow Developer Summit for how to use Tensorboard and generate an embedding with the MNIST dataset [here](https://github.com/mamcgrath/TensorBoard-TF-Dev-Summit-Tutorial/blob/master/mnist.py) that made it pretty easy to figure out how to implement one with my own dataset.

However, with their example, they generate their embedding using 1024 images in one run without any sort of batching. Is there any way to generate it via batching? There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to do so.

For example, if I want an embedding of 1000 images but can't compute all 1000 images at once, I want to "store" them in batches of say 50, and then the end result is still the 1000 images.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The code computes the embedding for the 1024 images when it runs  `sess.run(assignment, feed_dict={x: mnist.test.images[:1024], y: mnist.test.labels[:1024]})`. If you want to compute the embedding for just a subset of images, feed this subset and store those embeddings for that subset only (so, use many variables instead of a single one), while keeping the rest of the code the same.

Comment: Oh sorry, maybe I explained this poorly: I actually want to do the opposite. For example, if I want 1000 images but can't compute all 1000 images at once, I want to "store" them in batches of say 50, and then the end result is still the 1000 images.

Comment: Right, so make 200 variables, each fitting 50 images, and call  session.run on an op which assigns to each variable the result of feeding the subset of images you want to store for that variable

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you're saying now and I misunderstood previously, sorry! This is essentially what I am doing now except I basically kept over-writing the same variable, but I could easily make more and store them that way. However, doesn't that just enable me to swap between the (continuing with our example) 20 embeddings since it's storing them separately? I want it to functionally seem no different than if I had run all 1000 at once and stored it in 1 variable (that is, view all 1000 at once). Is it possible? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I mean, you can always never assign to a variable and just fetch the results. I don't quite understand what you mean by functionally seeming no different.

Comment: By "functionally seeming no different", I meant that I wanted to view all the results simultaneously on one graph as if I had run all 1000 at once and not batched them, not swap my view to different batches/graphs. However, I have a feeling that due to the way the embeddings are calculated that creating a complete, combined batched view is simply not possible.